# With hdparm, why do I need to set a password before secure-erasing the drive?

Tags: security, password, disk, hdparm

To use hdparm's `--security-erase`, I need to provide a password; and for that to work, I need to first set a password. Why is that? i.e. if I've never set a security password for my drive, why wouldn't the secure erase functionality just work with no password specified?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mitigation against interrupting the erasure once it starts.

Once erasure starts, the only things you can do is either let the erasure finish, or set a new erasure password and wipe the drive from scratch. This ensures that there is no way to stop the erasure halfway and then try to read the remaining data.

Comment: I don't quite understand how that mitigation involves the password. If you started an erasure, you're not supposed to be able to stop it anyway. I mean, a half-erased drive is in some sort of a junk state. Why should that be different with or without a password?

Comment: If a drive contains important data, half a drive might still be important. An attacker could try to interrupt an erasure by, for example, interrupting power to drive. If power is interrupted, the only action the controller will allow without knowing the original password is to start a new wipe. The drive cannot be returned to a readable state until an erasure has completed.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: Why not allow starting a wipe with no password, in which case the controller will act the same way you describe, except that no password is accepted? i.e. only accept a wipe command?

Comment: The ATA Secure Erase standard was designed for maximum security (and to minimize human error). The assumption was that erasure should be a high-assurance activity that, once issued, was irrevocable. But it needed to be balanced with the potential need to return the drive to service. So in the likely rare circumstance that an erase command was issued, interrupted, but the password is not known, the user can simply start a *new* erase, with a *new* password. Once this new erasure is complete, the drive can be unlocked and returned to service. Otherwise, the drive remains locked and unusable.